# Keep getting incorrect apikey Elasticemail

Tags: php, post

Am using ElasticEmail API to send email from my php website. I am sure I copy pasted the correct API KEY. My account is active too. Here my code:

```
    $postStr = array(
    'apikey' => 'MY-KEY',
    'from' => $fromEmail,
    'fromName' => $fromEmail,
    'subject' => '[Bug Report]',
    'to' => $notifyEmail,
    'bodyHtml' => $bugDetails,
    'isTransactional' => true);


    var_dump($postStr);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ));

    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

     echo $result;
```

vardump content:

> array(7) { ["apikey"]=> string(36) "----my apikey here-----"
>   ["from"]=> string(20) "genecode@gmail.com" ["fromName"]=> string(20)
>   "genecode@gmail.com" ["subject"]=> string(12) "[Bug Report]" ["to"]=>
>   string(23) "genecode@gmail.com" ["bodyHtml"]=> string(4) "Test"
>   ["isTransactional"]=> bool(true) }

result is:

```
{"success":false,"error":"Incorrect apikey"}
```

I don't know where I did wrong.

EDIT: I tried installing Postman. And test it there seems to work. I guess something wrong with my array building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found answer. It seems my guess was correct that the way I build the postfields was incorrect. Correct way is to use http_build_query on the array before passing it to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Then it works ok.

Code:

```
$postSafe = http_build_query($postStr);
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postSafe,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it right you should run json_encode on params array

```
$postStr = json_encode(array(
'apikey' => 'MY-KEY',
'from' => $fromEmail,
'fromName' => $fromEmail,
'subject' => '[Bug Report]',
'to' => $notifyEmail,
'bodyHtml' => $bugDetails,
'isTransactional' => true));
```

or send params as formdata.
Please note sending apikey in query string is not safe solution (and this what you doing with http_build_query). You can use also our offical [api library](https://github.com/ElasticEmail/ElasticEmail.WebApiClient-php) , which will cover this for you.